# How to access ArrayList from custom adapter class, when the ArrayList is stored in a class that extends Application

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, custom-adapter

I've created a class that extends Application which stores an ArrayList with several values.
The class is used to store values throughout the application so I can access them whenever needed.

However, I'm unable to call 'getApplicationContext()' in my custom adapter class because I get the following error:

> error: cannot find symbol method getApplicationContext()

If I am correct, it's because the custom adapter class does not extend AppCompatActivity.

Anyone know of a work around for this? Ultimately, I'm trying to create a ListView from the stored ArrayList.

My code is below.

```
public class CartListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {
    private ArrayList<Product> products;

    public CartListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Product> products ) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, products);

        this.products=products;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_cart_row_item, parent, false);


        final Global globalVariables = (Global) getApplicationContext();

        //get product stored in array that exists in Application class
        Product p = globalVariables.getMyProducts(position);


        TextView name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.cart_product_name);
        TextView price = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.cart_product_price);
        TextView quantity = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.cart_quantity_text);
        TextView type = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.cart_type);
        TextView option = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.cart_option);


        name.setText(p.getProductName());
        price.setText(p.getProductPrice());
        quantity.setText(p.getProductQuantity());
        type.setText(p.getProductType());
        option.setText(p.getProductOption());

        return row;
    }
}

public class Global extends Application {


private ArrayList <Product> myProducts = new ArrayList<>();
    private Cart cart;

    public Cart getCart() {

        return cart;
    }

    public void setCart(Cart cart) {

        this.cart = cart;
    }

    public Product getMyProducts(int position) {
        return myProducts.get(position);
    }

    public void addMyProducts(Product product) {
        myProducts.add(product);
    }

    public int getMyProductsSize (){
        return myProducts.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Make the list `static`. However, it is not good form to have data within the Application class if it can be placed elsewhere.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext(). Context is a param in your adapter use that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `getApplicationContext()` you should use `getContext().getApplicationContext()`, given that you're using it inside an `ArrayAdapter`.

[Context docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()) and [ArrayAdapter docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getContext()).

Comment: This has resolved the issue, the error no longer pops up. Thanks.